# How to start a process and attach it to the terminal corresponding to the local graphical shell?

Tags: lubuntu, lightdm, remote

I'm running Lubuntu 13.04 using `lightdm` as my login environment.

If I'm logged in to the graphical session and start my process, everything is groovy. But if I start the process remotely (ssh session), it tries to draw a window through ssh, and fails. I need it to draw the window locally (on the physically attached terminal). How can do I this?

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly your question, but I guess that `export DISPLAY` might be your friend.

Answer (score 0):

X-server where xclients are connected are defined by DISPLAY variable. For first local Xserver it's usually :0.0.
So - if you're logged remotly for machine with local Xserver, and you're want to run something locally - set:
export DISPLAY=:0.0
and then run your Xclient application - it'll connect to /tmp/.X11-unix/X0, and run localy.

But - if you wish to skip ssh forwarding and run xwindow application remotly without ssh - you can do it too - you must open Xserver to accept remote connections, add xclient using xhost, and then define variable DISPLAY to ip:xserwer